# Which of the following produces more current?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-electrodynamics, photoelectric-effect

In (1) photoelectric effect, (2) Compton effect, and (3) pair production, a beam of electrons are released. Out of Three Which produces More current?
And How?

Answer (score 0):

Two things are actually mixed in the question. Simple answer, one photon kicks out one electron in photoeffect, that (together with the hole) you can detect as a current.

1/ Gamma (photon) interaction with matter: you can have three scenarios - pair production (electron+positron), Compton effect and photoeffect.

2/ In photoeffect - electron kicks out an electron from the atomic orbit and disappears. The other two processes deposit energy, but there is still always some photon after, that may undergo the photoeffect.

This way you can imagine e.g. this cascade of events -  gamma ($E_\gamma$$\gt$1022 keV) undergoing pair creation, positron fastly annihilates to two $\gamma$ each of 511 keV, these $\gamma$ could interact by Compton effect and both finally absorbed by photoeffect. One electron created, but one electron consumed in annihilation, some electrons kicked by Compton, two electrons kicked out during photoeffect. This scenario kicks two electrons.

Comment: Its clear But Which One Produces More Current ?

Comment: Try to reformulate - the is no beam of electrons released. Give a real life scenario: do you speak about a gamma detector and collected current during one gamma event? Or ionization chamber collecting current long-term? Or something else?